# Caught ThreadStateException when using SaveFileDialog

Tags: c#, asp.net, closedxml

I got a problem with `SaveFileDialog`. The background is that I want to Export the data from a GridView to an Excel File. I am using ClosedXML for that, but the problem is that the file is directly exported to a assigned folder. 
 Meanwhile, I need a window that show where to save the file. That's why I am using `SaveFileDialog`.

This is my code:

```
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd hhmm tt");

SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel File (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx";
saveFileDialog1.FileName = "EmployeeData " + date + ".xlsx";
saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save the Excel File";

XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook();
wb.Worksheets.Add(bl.BindGridViewHasil(txtEmployeeCode.Text, txtEmployeeNumber.Text), "Sheet1");

if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    wb.SaveAs(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
}
```

And when I try to run that, I got this:

> An exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadStateException' occurred
>   in System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Current thread must be set to single thread
>   apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your
>   Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it. This exception is
>   only raised if a debugger is attached to the process.

Maybe someone can help me on this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Your question is tagged [tag:asp.net]. If you're running this in an ASP.Net context then, *even if it had worked*, you'd be opening a Save File dialog *on the server*, not on the machine where the user's browser is running. You don't get that sort of control with web applications. You can send files to the browser, as part of a separate request/response cycle, but then you have to rely on browser behaviour for what prompts it gives to the user for saving the file.

Comment: Your question is tagged [tag:closedxml]. I'm a maintainer on ClosedXML. I think @Damien_The_Unbeliever 's comment is correct and I don't think your problem is related to ClosedXML at all.

Comment: OP can you please provide more context.  Is this an ASP.NET application, a Windows Forms app, or what?  Does this code execute on a worker thread and not on the main thread?